# Problems with using a .tsv file that contains JSON as a data feed file in Gatling

Tags: json, scala, csv, gatling

I am using Gatling to stress test a RESTful API.  I will be posting data that is JSON to a particular URI. I want to use a feed file that is a .tsv where each line is a particular JSON element.  However, I get errors and I just can't seem to find a pattern or system to add "" to my .tsv JSON so the feed will work.  Attached is my code and tsv file.

```
package philSim

import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.http.Predef._
import scala.concurrent.duration._

class eventAPISimulation extends Simulation {

  object Query {
    val feeder = tsv("inputJSON.tsv").circular
    val query = forever {
      feed(feeder)
      .exec(
        http("event")
        .post("my/URI/here")
        .body(StringBody("${json}")).asJSON
      )
    }
  } 

  val httpConf = http.baseURL("my.url.here:portnumber")

  val scn = scenario("event").exec(Query.query)

   setUp(scn.inject(rampUsers(100) over (30 seconds)))
        .throttle(reachRps(2000) in (30 seconds), holdFor(3 minutes))
        .protocols(httpConf)
}
```

Here is an example of my unedited .tsv with JSON:

```
json
{"userId":"234342234","secondaryIdType":"mobileProfileId","secondaryIdValue":"66666638","eventType":"push","eventTime":"2015-01-23T23:20:50.123Z","platform":"iPhoneApp","notificationId":"123456","pushType":1,"action":"sent","eventData":{}}
{"userId":"234342234","secondaryIdType":"mobileProfileId","secondaryIdValue":"66666638","eventType":"INVALID","eventTime":"2015-01-23T23:25:20.342Z","platform":"iPhoneApp","notificationId":"123456","pushType":1,"action":"received","eventData":{"osVersion":"7.1.2","productVersion":"5.9.2"}}
{"userId":"234342234","secondaryIdType":"mobileProfileId","secondaryIdValue":"66666638","eventType":"push","eventTime":"2015-01-23T23:27:30.342Z","platform":"iPhoneApp","notificationId":"123456","pushType":1,"action":"followedLink","eventData":{"deepLinkUrl":"URL.IS.HERE","osVersion":"7.1.2","productVersion":"5.9.2"}}
{"userId":"234342234","secondaryIdType":"mobileProfileId","secondaryIdValue":"66666638","eventType":"push","eventTime":"2015-01-23T23:27:30.342Z","platform":"AndroidApp","notificationId":"123456","pushType":1,"action":"followedLink","eventData":{"deepLinkUrl":"URL.IS.HERE"}}
{"userId":"234342234","secondaryIdType":"mobileProfileId","secondaryIdValue":"66666638","eventType":"push","eventTime":"2015-01-23T23:25:20.342Z","platform":"iPhoneApp","notificationId":"123456","pushType":1,"action":"error","eventData":{}}
```

I have seen [this blog post](https://ahlearns.wordpress.com/2014/01/16/gatling-stress-tool-example-simulation-with-a-circular-feed/) which talks about manipulating quotation marks (") to get the author's JSON with .tsv to work but the author doesn't offer a system how.  I have tried various things and nothing I do really works.  Some JSON will work with the quotation wrap similar to what the author of the paper does.  However, this doesn't work for everything.  What are the best practices for dealing with JSON and Gatling?  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Straight from [Gatling's documentation](http://gatling.io/docs/2.1.4/session/feeder.html#csv-feeders) : Use `rawSplit` so that Gatling's TSV parser will be able to handle your JSON entries:

```
tsv("inputJSON.tsv", rawSplit = true).circular
```

Comment: Thank you! I swear I read the documentation... I need to learn to take a deep breath and read slower, not in a panic state!